# FAB Group Button isnt Setting State - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to coding, react native and mobile app development. 
I am trying to build water reminder app.

I have FAB group button which shows different type of drinks. When users click second FAB button with (hamburger menu icon), it opens and I want to set state by water amount of selected. Then this state is passed to progress circle to calculate the progres.

However obviously I am not able to update the state properly because I receive an error that progress.circle received NaN value

[image]

```
const goal = 2000;

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

  state = {
    progress: 0,
    drunk: 0,
    open: false
  };

  drinkOther = drink => {
    let bottle = 500;
    let bigBottle = 1000;
    let coffee = 200;
    let tea = 200;
    let progress = this.state.progress;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      drunk: prevState.drunk + drink,
      progress: (prevState.drunk + drink) / goal
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Portal>
              <FAB.Group
                open={this.state.open}
                icon={"menu"}
                actions={[
                  {
                    icon: require("../assets/images/juice.png"),
                    label: "Juice",
                    onPress: this.drinkOther("juice")
                  },
                  {
                    icon: require("../assets/images/coffee.png"),
                    label: "Coffee",
                    onPress: this.drinkOther("coffee")
                  },
                  {
                    icon: require("../assets/images/tea.png"),
                    label: "Tea",
                    onPress: this.drinkOther("tea")
                  },
                  {
                    icon: require("../assets/images/big_bottle.png"),
                    label: "Big Bottle",
                    onPress: this.drinkOther("bigBottle")
                  },
                  {
                    icon: require("../assets/images/bottle.png"),
                    label: "Small Bottle",
                    onPress: this.drinkOther("bottle")
                  }
                ]}
                onStateChange={({ open }) => this.setState({ open })}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
                }}
                style={styles.fab}
                color={"white"}
                theme={{ colors: { accent: Colors.tintColor } }}
              />
            </Portal>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
```

Comment: You're trying to divide by "goal" but it doesnt look like goal was ever defined in your event handler. Which is why you're getting a NaN

Comment: I defined goal just above my HomeScreen because it is also used by other event handlers (other glass FAB button). Where should I move @yourfavoritedev

Comment: make `goal` a class member or put it in `State`

Comment: @kai I changed it to state and I receive this error. 'error while updating property d in shadow node of type artshape null'

Comment: You're trying to divide a string by a number.

Comment: @kai how is that possible. Both drunk and goal states are defined as integer.   state = {
    progress: 0,
    drunk: 0,
    goal: 2000,
  };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this `setState` call in `drinkOther`:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  drunk: prevState.drunk + drink,
  progress: (prevState.drunk + drink) / goal
}));
```

If you look at where `drink` comes from, it's the argument that you're passing to `drinkOther`:

```
onPress: this.drinkOther("juice")
```

You're trying to add the string "juice", "coffee", or whatever to the `drunk` total and then divide it by a number, which of course returns NaN.

Comment: @ahh I see. What is the ideal solution for this? using if statement or switch for each drink?

Comment: You could put your drink values in an object, like so: `let drinks = {bottle: 500, bigBottle: 1000...}` and then use the drinkOther argument to grab the object key: `drunk: (prevState.drunk + drinks[drink]) / goal`

Comment: very good idea. Now I receive this error. 'Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`).Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.' I guess I am calling drinkOther argument immediately in render method

Comment: I was doing sth wrong in onPress. I changed it from 'onPress: this.drinkOther("juice")' to '() => onPress: this.drinkOther("juice")' . after this change no error was thrown